# Some PHP codes aren't running in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2, php, csv

I'm very frustrated because of PHP codes that are not executing in my Ubuntu 20.04 but working smoothly in windows 10. There are many codes that are not running I have attached one.

```
              `<?php
              if(isset($_POST['sub']))
              {

                  $user=$_POST['user'];
                  $pass=$_POST['pass'];
                  $file=fopen("userdetails.csv","r");
                  while(($row=fgetcsv($file))!==false)
                  {
                  if($row[0]===$user)
                  {
                      die("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
                      Username '$user' is already exists. 
                      </div>");
                  }
                  
                  }
                  
                      // echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
                      // Login details saved successfully!
                      // </div>";
                      $fileappend=fopen("users.csv","a");
                      $data=array($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']);
                      fputcsv($fileappend,$data) or die("ERROR");
                      //  sleep(0.5);
                      fclose($file);
                      fclose($fileappend);
                        header("Location:homepage.html");
              }
              ?>`
```

In windows `fputcsv() and header("Location: homepage.html")` functions are working fine
but showing nothing or ERROR as I wrote here `or die("ERROR")` All I'm asking is, Is there any software or any package or anything I have to install for running those???
I have install php7* and apache2. is there anything else I have to do that I haven't done yet???

Comment: php does not allow you to write the actual error to disk?  and no you do not need any more software: apache + php + configuration in apache is enough. I hate php though ;-)

Comment: Gut instinct, add an `or die("File not found")` after the `fopen`s.

Comment: There may be an actionable error message explaining the failure in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Installing *all* PHP packages seems excessive, but shouldn’t prevent you from running what you’ve written. One word of warning, though, the code snippet you’ve shared has a number of serious security concerns. It would be unwise to use this on an internet-facing website 